# Unable to start node manager on hadoop 0.23.0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

while installing Hadoop 0.23.0 on the cluster, node manager is unable to start and getting the following error.

```
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
        at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler.start(ShuffleHandler.java:255)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices.start(AuxServices.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.service.CompositeService.start(CompositeService.java:68)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:126)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
```

Answer (score 1):

It means 8080 is already in use. 
so 
sudo netstat -nvvpa |grep 8080 and see the o/p.

if it listens to any java, then if possible stop the process. and then try to start the nodemanager again.

This made my problem solved. thankyou.